# Can I programatically refresh an Outlook entity view? (online 2013)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

Our setup is Outlook 2010 + CRM addin connected to a 2013 online instance.

I have some custom ribbon buttons on the lead grid ribbon that manipulate selected leads. After certain operations, I would like to tell Outlook to refresh the current view as the operation has updated selected leads so they should no longer show in the current view.

Currently, I have to explain to users that the view updates on its own schedule and they must manually refresh the view (View tab/Refresh button) if they want it to happen immediately. Not surprisingly I am getting a lot of complaints about this!

[This](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0aa9f16-eb15-468a-8b23-2964791adb85/refresh-data-in-outlook-view-in-crm-2011?forum=crm) seems to suggest that there is a way to programmatically refresh the view but I don't understand the details of how to get it working.

[Here](http://mscrmonline.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/how-to-refresh-a-microsoft-crm-2011-outlook-client-view/) is some info with pics on the manual refresh.

Here's a pic of the Outlook view I need to refresh with custom button JS:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view can be refreshed in 2011 in an unsupported manner, so this code may not work in 2013 and may break with some update rollups.
The anonymous function must be in an library that is referenced by a ribbon button; there are no events or Xrm object on views.
I created a new hidden ribbon button ([Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/Download%20Ribbon%20Workbench%202013.aspx) works well) that had an action that referenced the JavaScript library that contained this function; the function does not need to be called - it runs when the library is loaded.

```javascript
var seconds = 30;
/*  
 * @param {int} inSeconds: how often the view should refresh in seconds  
 * */ 
(function (inSeconds) {     
    var interval = setInterval(function () {         
        document.getElementById("crmGrid").control.refresh();     
    }, inSeconds * 1000); 
}(seconds));
// The line to refresh the grid is not supported
```

What can be done in a supported manner is to refresh a sub-grid on a form; if you could get users to work from a form instead of a view you can use this supported code and call it in a manner like above or rather on the onload event:

```javascript
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("sub_grid_name").refresh();
```

Comment: Many thanks. Rather than refresh on a period (the unsupported way), can I call the unsupported method from my custom button JS so I only refresh as needed? That should work, right? I need to work at the view level as users often need to apply the same operation to multiple selected records

Comment: Calling from the button action will work just as well. Please mention if the unsupported code works in 2013 once you have tried it.

Comment: Should get to trying it soon and will update. Can you explain how you go about finding the Id of the view (crmGrid)? I'd need to be able to quickly adapt should it change...

Comment: I don't know, you could use the browser's debugger to try to locate it. Using the DOM in CRM is dodgy, it is possible that more than the name changes in a future update rollup.

Comment: I know how to locate the elementId in the browser client but it's an Outlook client view (no browser until you get to a form) so not sure how that works.

Comment: If you view the source of any view in the browser it will be fine; the command to refresh the view does not change from view to view or entity to entity.

Comment: have added pic in an attempt to clarify. The view in question is part of the Outlook client UI so I can't "view it in a browser". Are you saying that whatever the elementId of the view is in a browser, that it'll be the same for the Outlook UI view? Confused...

Comment: Yes, but "crmGrid" is not the name of a particular view. The name stays the same for all views on all entities - it will only change (possibly) in an update rollup. In any case if that view, All Pipeline, is a system view you can view it in the browser; this is not relevant to your question, but why can you not view it in the browser?

Comment: Holy crap, it works! I added your document.getElement... line at the end of my custom button JS, exactly as you have it, and sure enough, it refreshes the current view in the outlook client. Also works in IE client (connected to 2013 online). Thanks Bvrce!