# In dynamics crm 2013 Form not get dirty when add related records

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

In MS Dynamics CRM I want to call post/pre update plugin when new related record is added. I think it can be done by using JS by refreshing the page but will look for other solution without page flicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may have to periodically query CRM with JavaScript and update the sub-grid when a new record has been added. There is no way to push the update to the form when the related record has been added, you will have to pull it with JavaScript.

Here is the JavaScript to refresh a sub-grid:

```javascript
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("sub_grid_name").refresh();
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609530/can-i-programatically-refresh-an-outlook-entity-view-online-2013/21620585#21620585) may be relevant.

Comment: Hi, It is actually the other way around i.e I want to call some server side logic (plugin) on refreshing of subgrid.

Comment: There is no CRM event fired when the subgrid is refreshed. The plugin could fire on create of the related record rather than on the primary record.